# How to convert a flat array to a tree with a specific maximum depth?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, object, tree

I have a data like this:

```js
[
  {
    id: "1",
    parent: null
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    parent: null
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    parent: "1"
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    parent: "3"
  },
]
```

And I want to convert it to a tree with a specific maximum depth. There are a few ways to convert an array to a tree, for example [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/performant-array-to-tree) but the problem is they go all the way trough and create a deeply nested tree:

```js
[
  {
    data: { id: "1", parent: null },
    children: [
      {
        data: { id: "3", parent: "1" }
        children: [
          {
            id: "4", parent: "3"
          } 
        ] 
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    data: { id: "2", parent: null }
  }
]
```

I don't want the depth of the tree be more than a specific amount, let say 1:

```js
[
  {
    data: { id: "1", parent: null },
    children: [
      {
        data: { id: "3", parent: "1" }  
      },
      {
        data: { id: "4", parent: "3" } 
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    data: { id: "2", parent: null }
  }
]
```

One way is to first create the deeply nested object and then flatten the parts that I don't want to be nested, but it might change the order of items + it's inefficient. I've had a couple of tries to create an algorithm myself but I'm not generally good at these type of stuff. I would appreciate some help. Idea, example, anything could be useful.

Comment: Can you show your efforts?

Comment: When you say it is inefficient, what do you mean? If it is well done it has O(n) time complexity, and since you need to inspect the complete data, there is no way you can hope to do better than that.

Comment: *"It might change the order of items"*: is that so? It depends on how you implement it. Please show your code.

Comment: Hey @trincot. Sorry for the delayed response, I didn't want to be rude. 1) My efforts are a bunch of ugly code that doesn't work. I don't want to add such things to the question. 2) Yeah I know if it's done right it could be efficient enough but I couldn't find the right way 3) Yes, it depends on how I implement it but when I ask a question here it means that I can't implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses a little recursive [generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) to get the desired ancestor of the node based on the specified depth:

```js
const treeify = (nodes, depth) => {
  const index = Object.fromEntries(
    nodes.map(node => [node.id, { ...node }])
  );
  const ancestry = function*(id) {
    if (id) {
      yield id;
      yield* ancestry(index[id].parent);
    }
  }
  
  nodes.forEach(node => {
    const [ancestor] = [...ancestry(node.parent)].slice(-depth);
    
    if (ancestor) {
      index[ancestor].children = index[ancestor].children || [];
      index[ancestor].children.push(index[node.id]);
    }
  });
  
  return Object.values(index).filter(node => !node.parent);
}

const data = [
  { id: "1", parent: null }, { id: "2", parent: null},
  { id: "3", parent: "1" }, { id: "4", parent: "3" }
];

console.log(treeify(data, 1));
```

I got rid of the superfluous `data` property. It wasn't being used consistently in your question anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This code builds the tree using a standard recursive approach, except when the specified depth is reached. At that depth, it builds a flat array instead of continuing to build out the tree.

```js
const d = [{id:"1",parent:null},{id:"2",parent:null},
           {id:"3",parent:"1"},{id:"4",parent:"3"}];

const f = (depth, p=null) => d.filter(i => i.parent===p).map(i => depth>0 ?
  {data:i, children: f(depth-1, i.id)} : [{data:i}, ...f(0,i.id).flat()]);

console.log(f(1));
```

However, the code above will order the 'flat' parts of the tree according to the tree hierarchy. To ensure that the 'flat' parts contain items in the same order as the original data, include a sort:

```js
const d = [{id:"1",parent:null},{id:"2",parent:null},
           {id:"3",parent:"1"},{id:"4",parent:"3"}];

const lookup = ({data:{id}}) => d.findIndex(d=>id===d.id);

const f = (depth, p=null) => d.filter(i => i.parent===p).map(i => depth>0 ?
  {data:i, children: f(depth-1, i.id)} : [{data:i}, ...f(0,i.id).flat()]
  .sort((a,b)=>lookup(a)-lookup(b)));

console.log(f(1));
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to write this. The sorting is exactly what I want to avoid. My data is already being sorted, I don't like the idea of sorting it again. I approved the "Robby Cornelissen" answer because I like it more and it seems more efficient. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

You'll anyway have to iterate all of the data, so use that iteration to inverse the relationship and collect for each parent the list of children ids. This almost looks like the complete tree structure you want to avoid, but it uses less memory, as these arrays only consist of ids, not of objects. And, you really need to have a fast look up and avoid repeated iterations over the same input (like with `find`).

This intermediate structure is an adjacency list. In a second phase it can be used to build the limited tree object structure:

```js
const createAdjacencyList = data =>
    data.reduce((graph, {id, parent}) =>
        ((graph[parent] ??= []).push(id), graph)
    , {});

const createTree = (adj, depth, parent=null) =>
    adj[parent].map(id => ({
        id, parent,
        ...depth && adj[id] && { 
            children: createTree(adj, depth-1, id) 
        }
    }));

// Example
const data = [{id: "1",parent: null},{id: "2",parent: null},{id: "3",parent: "1"},{id: "4",parent: "3"}];
const adj = createAdjacencyList(data);
const tree = createTree(adj, 1);
console.log(tree);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to write this. I'm not smart enough to figure out what's going on in your algorithm, but when I run the code snippet, item 4 is not in the result. I approved the "Robby Cornelissen" answer because I like it more. Thank you again.

Comment: Just to explain that item 4 is not in the result because it is too deep. The example runs with depth 1, while node 4 sits at depth 2, and so it is excluded.